# How to create complex dynamic queries in EF Core 3.1 after breaking changes?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.0, .net-core-3.1

I have this function that returns an `IQueryable`:

```
private IQueryable<string> GetActiveCellPhoneNumbersUpToDate(long serviceToken, DateTime date, bool? isPrepaid = null)
{
    var to = date.AddDays(1).Date;
    var query = ViewRepository
        .All
        .Where(i => i.ServiceToken == serviceToken)
        .Where(i => i.Date < to);
    if (isPrepaid.HasValue)
    {
        query = query.Where(i => i.IsPrepaid == isPrepaid);
    }
    query = query.OrderByDescending(i => i.Date);
    var result = query
        .GroupBy(i => i.CellPhoneNumber)
        .Where(i => i.First().ActionId == (int)SubscriptionAction.Subscription)
        .SelectMany(i => i.ToList())
        .Select(i => i.CellPhoneNumber)
        .Distinct();
    return result;
}
```

and this function would be called another function for only counting:

```
var prepaidsCount = GetActiveCellPhoneNumbersUpToDate(serviceToken, DateTime.Date, true);
var postPaidsCount = GetActiveCellPhoneNumbersUpToDate(serviceToken, DateTime.Date, false);
```

And when I execute it I see [a breaking change of EF 3.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#linq-queries-are-no-longer-evaluated-on-the-client), that says:

> Processing of the LINQ expression 'i => i
>       .ToList()' by 'NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor' failed. This may indicate either a bug or a limitation in EF Core. See
>   https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101433 for more detailed
>   information.

As stated in the breaking change notes, I need to user `AsEnumerable` or `ToList` before complex `Where` clauses to execute that portion of LINQ and bring data into RAM, then continue my query.

But for large amounts of data with the need of dynamic queries, this is absolutely insane and unimaginably inefficient.

What is the substitute for this? How can we create dynamic complex queries to be translated at runtime and only return a singular scalar value?

**Update:** Real-world requirements are not hello-world examples. They need complex filtering and sorting and grouping and other functions, mixed together, to extract data from a relational structure. In the past we would use Stored Procedures for those purposes. Passing a couple of parameters to database, and writing ugly, hard-to-test, far-from-maintainable, weekly-typed, refactor-resistant SQL code to fetch data.

Now the only option that comes to my mind is downgrading back to those ugly Stored Procedures. Is this nightmare a reality in EF 3.1?

**Update 2:** This is my scenario. I have a table in which I store cell phone number subscription/cancellations in specific services. The simplified version of that table would be:

```
create table Subscriptions
(
    Id,
    CellPhoneNumber,
    ServiceId,
    Date,
    ActionId
)
```

And these can be records:

```
John,+1-541-754-3010,15,2019-10-13 12:10:06.153,1
John,+1-541-754-3010,15,2019-10-18 12:10:06.153,2
```

Here we can see that John has subscribed to service 15, and has remained in it for 5 days, and then he has cancelled. If we want to report how many subscriber did we have at *2019-10-14*, John would be counted. Because in that time, his last action was to enroll. But if we want to report how many subscribers did we have at `2910-11-03` then John's last action was to leave the service and he should not be counted.

Comment: What you linked to isn't a breaking change. It detected the bugs you already had in your code. EF 6.2 would also throw an exception instead of using client-side evaluation. That thing is a *bug*, not a feature. It's only *real* use was covering up for deficiencies in EF Core 1.x and 2.x (no GROUP BY for example). Until now, your code would fail to create a single SQL query for the original LINQ query and pull most of the data on the client and filter it there. Needless to say, this is *very* slow and inefficient

Comment: Why it's a bug? This code has been working just fine without a bug. Basically I have a table of subscriptions and cancellations for a bunch of services, and all I want to know is to find out how many subscribers a service had up to a date. This is a singular scalar value and I don't want to fetch the whole data into RAM just to count it. The only way that I know now is to jump back to stored procedures, which I think is moving back in terms of technology.

Comment: You mean my code brings the entire data into memory already?

Comment: Exactly. If you used SQL Server Profiler or Extended Events you'd see that the SQL query was a bit unexpected

Comment: For example `.SelectMany(i => i.ToList())` ? How can this be translated to SQL? What does it even mean? SQL results aren't nested, they don't need SelectMany

Comment: Then as I've mentioned in the title of the question, how can we create complex dynamic queries in EF Core? I mean, real-world requirements need grouping data, filtering and sorting, and sometimes a couple of them mixed together. This way, we always have to get away from EF for these scenarios. Am I right, or do I miss something here?

Comment: `.Where(i => i.First().ActionId == (int)SubscriptionAction.Subscription)` on a *group*?  This looks like it's trying to ungroup the group and pick a random `ActionId`. In SQL you'd use `GROUP BY` and either MIN(ActionID)` or `MAX(ActionID)` to retrieve the "first" or "last" ID, or a window function like `First_Value` or `Last_Value`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I've sorted the data before that. This code works. It's not a random `ActionId`, it's the first `ActionId` from now, or in other words, last action a subscriber has taken. If his last action was subscription, then he's in the service, then we count him.

Comment: The question is wrong. You didn't have complex queries to begin with, they were bad queries, that make no sense in *SQL itself*. LINQ can't do things that SQL itself can't do. Think again what you want to do, think how you'd do it in SQL and write that LINQ query. If the query looks too complex *DON'T DO IT with an ORM*. ORMs are meant to Map Objects to Relational tables. Not for reporting queries that return just data. LINQ weakens that restriction but only up to a point. Reporting queries typically belong to the database, eg as views

Comment: You didn't sort the data. You *can't* sort the data after a `GROUP BY`, simply because the data is gone - it's either keys or aggregates. The only reason your query worked *before* is because the data wasn't grouped in the database

Comment: You can easily create views that make reporting easier and map them to objects with EF Core, especially using keyless entities.

Comment: Speaking of real-world requirements, that's why you can't use ORMs and LINQ for reporting queries, no matter what you see in demos. Although *good* tutorials and demoes never use ORMs for reporting queries, or generic repositories. Check [No need for repositories and unit of work with Entity Framework Core](https://gunnarpeipman.com/ef-core-repository-unit-of-work/) because I suspect there are some surprises hidden behind that ViewRepository too

Comment: Yeah, I know EF Core is already both repository and unit of work. That ViewRepository is not there to act as a repository. It's there to extend EF Core. Methods like `GetIfExists` or `GetByGuid` or `GetList(List<long> ids)` or other handy methods are not in the interface of EF Core. Thus we have to wrap it.

Comment: What are you trying to produce with that query? It's easier to come up with a solution if you explain your intent, not how you expected the query to look like. Find Cell numbers whose *latest* call was from a specific subscription? Or just find subscriptions in the last X days?

Comment: Eg. `query=calls.Where(i => i.ServiceToken == serviceToken && i.Date>=DateTime.Today.AddDays(-4) && i.ActionId == (int)SubscriptionAction.Subscription);if(..)query=query.Where(..);result=query.Distinct(i=>i.CellPhoneNumber).ToList()`

Comment: write the sql and i will write the linq, everything panagiotis has said is spot on, sometime is actually easier to write the sql for "complex" querys, and then convert that to linq as doing it in sql let you understand how the data must be structured in ways that is supported by the query lang

Answer (score 2):

Queries that depend on intervals, or the current state of a record, can be tricky. Normally, we'd have to search for subscriptions that have one status in the specified period but not the other. This would require at least one subquery or CTE. This can be expensive even with indexing, because it requires two seeks or scans over the target table.

Any trick that *avoids* this is welcome. In this particular case, where the action IDs are 1 and 2, a simple way to get active subscribers would be to get those whose MAX(ActionID) isn't 2, or is less than 2, eg :

```
SELECT COUNT(Distinct cellnumber)
FROM Subscriptions 
WHERE Date <=@reportDate ....
GROUP by CellNumber
HAVING MAX(ActionID)<2
```

The equivalent in LINQ would be

```
var actives= ctx.Subscriptions
                .Where(sub=>sub.Date <= reportDate )
                .GroupBy(sub=>sub.CellNumber)
                .Where(grp=>grp.Max(sub=>sub.ActionId)<2)  // Results in a HAVING clause
                .Distinct()
                .Count();
```

Adding the rest of the criteria :

```
var query = ctx.Subscriptions
                .Where(sub=>sub.Date <= reportDate && sub.ServiceToken == serviceToken);
if(isPrepaid.HasValue)
{
    query = query.Where(sub => sub.IsPrePaid==isPrepaid);
}

var actives= query.GroupBy(sub=>sub.CellNumber)
                  .Where(grp=>grp.Max(sub=>sub.ActionId)<2)
                  .Distinct()
                  .Count();
```

**SQL Server 2016 temporal tables**

If we are lucky enough to use SQL Server 2016 or later, we can convert `Subscriptions` into a temporal table and simply count the subscriptions with a specific state at a certain point in time. We could just use :

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CellPhoneNumber)
FROM Subscriptions  FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF @someTime
WHERE ActionID<2
```

EF Core doesn't support temporal tables directly, so we need to use [FromSqlRaw](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql) for that part of the query :

```
var query = ctx.Subscriptions
                .FromSqlRaw("select * from Subscriptions FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF {0}",
                            reportDate)
                .Where(sub=>sub.Date <= reportDate && sub.ServiceToken == serviceToken);
if(isPrepaid.HasValue)
{
    query = query.Where(sub => sub.IsPrePaid==isPrepaid);
}

var actives= query.Distinct()
                  .Count();
```

There's no grouping involved in that query. It doesn't depends on the actual number or order of the Action values, nor is it confused by multiple records per subscription.

Comment: I don't understand the temporal tables section. We query a table in a certain point in time. In that certain time, let's say John as subscribed 3 times, and has cancelled two times. The last state of John is subscription. So he has to be counted as subscribed in that point in time. How multiple records per subscription creates no confusion in the temporal table?